# Why is Maven trying to resolve a dependency from my company's repository when it isn't referenced in this project?

Tags: maven, vaadin

I am playing with Vaadin and want to use an add-on widgetset. I got a repository spec and a dependency to put in my maven file, which I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myCompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>Vaadin2</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Vaadin2</name>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <properties>
    <vaadin.version>7.7.1</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>7.7.1</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- If there are no local customisations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
    <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>vaadin-addons</id>
      <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
                <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flexibleoptiongroup</artifactId>
                   <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>update-theme</goal>
              <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
              <goal>compile-theme</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
       <configuration>
        <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/Vaadin2</runTarget>
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
        running jetty:run on the command line. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
      <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
          <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
          <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Then I attempt to update the widget set, which goes like this:

```
C:\Users\rcook\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject1\Vaadin2>mvn vaadin:update-widgetset install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Vaadin2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://gaia.myCompany.com:9080/archiva/repository/internal/org/vaadin/addons/flexibleoptiongroup/2.3.0/flexibleoptiongroup-2.3.0.pom

[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addons:flexibleoptiongroup:jar:2.3.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://gaia.myCompany.com:9080/archiva/repository/internal/org/vaadin/addons/flexibleoptiongroup/2.3.0/flexibleoptiongroup-2.3.0.jar

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.036s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 27 16:38:37 EDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Vaadin2: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myCompany:Vaadin2:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.vaadin.addons:flexibleoptiongroup:jar:2.3.0 in archiva.default (http://gaia.myCompany.com:9080/archiva/repository/internal/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
C:\Users\rcook\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject1\Vaadin2>
```

gaia is the name of a server within my company that holds the Maven repository for other projects, but I don't understand why Maven insists on looking there, or even how it knows about it in this instance. The string 'gaia' doesn't appear in the settings.xml at all. Where could it obtain the URL for the gaia repository, so I can turn it off for this project? And why doesn't maven use the repository I configured in the pom.xml for this project?

Windows 7, if that matters...

Comment: check your setting.xml file , you might have configured you company repos there.

Comment: as I said, it isn't in settings anywhere.

Comment: Try adding plugin repository

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a settings.xml? It would normally be in a hidden folder .m2 in your home directory.

Comment: As I said in the original post: "The string 'gaia' doesn't appear in the settings.xml at all." That implies heavily that there IS such a file, that I've looked in it and done a search through it, and that this string is not in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea would be the settings file. Did you check the `mvn dependency:effective-pom` to get more info on the project or `mvn help:effective-settings` for more details on the settings?

Comment: As I said in the original post, the string "gaia" does not appear in the settings file, so it doesn't contain the repository URL anywhere. I just now tried `mvn dependency:effective-pom`; it downloaded 6 poms for jetty that I don't recognize (I don't use jetty), then said it couldn't locate a goal for 'effective-pom'. I tried `mvn help:effective-settings', and it downloaded 10 more things I don't recognize (mostly to do with maven, it seems), and then printed out several hundred lines of pom; it lists a 'mirror' as being the server in question, so where is the mirror specified?

Comment: My bad, it was help:effective-pom. You can get more info on the [plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Comment: You found the mirror in the effective-settings so that's one step ahead.

Maven standard locations for it's settings are [the installation directory, your maven_home](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html). You can find their values by running `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=user.home`

If it is not in your user.home then the actual definition must come from the installation directory of maven.